# Typescript: Interface Object property

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have 2 interfaces: fooParent and fooDetail. Now, in fooDetails: childTitle  property should be made from fooParent two properties as below:

```
export interface fooParent {
   appId: string,
   appName: string
}

export interface fooDetail {
  childTitle: fooParent.appId + '-' + fooParent.appName
}
```

How can I achieve following:

> `childTitle: fooParent.appId + '-' + fooParent.appName`

Comment: Consider [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEPzgW) example

Answer (score 1):

You can use template literal strings:

```js
export interface fooParent {
    appId: string,
    appName: string
}

export interface fooDetail {
    childTitle: `${fooParent['appId']} - ${fooParent['appName']}`
}
```

If you are interested in inference, you can check this example:

```js
export interface fooParent {
    appId: string,
    appName: string
}

export interface fooDetail {
    childTitle: `${fooParent['appId']} - ${fooParent['appName']}`
}

const handler = <
    Id extends string,
    Name extends string,
    Parent extends fooParent & { appId: Id, appName: Name }
>(parent: Parent): `${Parent['appId']} - ${Parent['appName']}` =>
    `${parent.appId} - ${parent.appName}`

const result = handler({ appId: '#1', appName: 'App' }) // "#1 - App"
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w2PbYm)